# Moto e4+ fast charging issues

Tags: charging, battery-life, motorola, battery-history

My moto e4 plus is 2yrs old.Suddenly at 75-80% it's charging rate drops then after a while suddenly it charging very fast after that stoppage.can anyone tell me reason !please